# How to select a Zebra_Datepicker using tab key

Tags: javascript, jquery

When in a form, and I press the Tab key to move to the next input, and the focus reaches the date input, the date picker won't show.

I tried doing something like this:

```
$(elem).focus(function () {
    $(this).data('Zebra_DatePicker').show();
});
```

But it shows and hides immediately.

I think the DatePicker should be shown when the element gets the focus.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(elem).focus(function () {
    $(this).click();
});
```